# RecyclerView: Nested clickable views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` which has 2 `Buttons` inside its item and also swipable `ViewPager`. I need to set `onClickListener` for entire `RecyclerView` item but also allow to interact with ViewPager by swiping and those 2 Buttons.

Is this possible. I tried everything. Tried to set every single `View` to `clickable false`. Only `Buttons` and `RecyclerView` item parent is clickable. Also added to parent view `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` but none of this worked.

`ViewPager` is not clickable only swipable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this issue normally, but I solved it by little hack, I set `onClickListener` for each page of `ViewPager` and sent `onClick` function as parameter from RecyclerView item. This way clicking on page of the `ViewPager` will do the same as root in `onBindViewHolder` for its parent.

onClick listener is set inside custom `ViewPagerAdapter` right before I return layout to `ViewPager` in `instantiateItem()` function.

If I wanted to achieve onClick for entire item, I will probably never wanted to click on `ViewPager` item to perform other action. It would be bad design. Swiping `ViewPager` inside `RecyclerView` is not triggering onClick event so its fine.